# Can we specify an positioned element for absolutely positioned elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

An absolutely positioned element is always positioned in relative to it closest positioned ancestor. I wonder if there are some ways i can specify an reference Element for the absolutely positioned element, not just the closest positioned ancestor? (CSS or jquery)

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Comment: Why don't you just make it a child of that ancestor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant. But what about just adding (/ moving) it to that element:

```
$('#absoluteElement').appendTo('#relativeToElement');
```

Answer (score 1):

Afraid not! I'm sure plenty of UI developers have dreamed of using something like this though…

```
relative-to: #arbitrary .selector;
```

Comment: yes, i really want that kind of functions, especially when I'm using other people's javascript plugins that affect other layout. Hope someday we can use the above code.